# Finite morphism "with the right number of equations"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a scheme, say smooth, connected of finite type over a field of characteristic zero, $Y \to X$ is a smooth morphism of relative dimension $d$, and $f_1, \dots, f_d \in \mathcal{O}(Y)$ are $d$ global sections. Let $Z = Z(f_1, \dots, f_d) \subset Y$ be the closed (not necessarily reduced) subscheme defined by the global sections. Assume that the composite $Z \to X$ is finite.

What can be concluded in this situation? As far as I understand if $Z$ happened to be integral then it would be Cohen-Macaylay and flat over $X$. Is there something that can be said in greater generality? What if I assume that $X$ is the spectrum of a Henselian local ring, for example?

Related question: [Are finite correspondances flat?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51991/are-finite-correspondances-flat)

Comment: Your assumption that $Z \to X$ is finite implies that $Z$ is lci (since $X$ and $Y$ are smooth). So, $Z$ is also Cohen--Macaulay, hence it is flat over $X$ without any  further assumptions.

Comment: Are you saying that the $f_i$ automatically form a regular sequence? Do you have a reference? I am afraid my ignorance of geometry is showing :/.

Comment: Yes, the $f_i$ indeed form a regular sequence. See, for example, Theorem 2.12 (c) of the book "Cohen-Macaulay rings" by Bruns--Herzog (or any other commutative algebra book which discusses regular sequences).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: (For anyone else looking, it's theorem 2.1.2 (c) in the book cited.)

Comment: Are you willing to look at perverse etale sheaves?:)

Comment: @MikhailBondarko: I don't follow.

Comment: This is actually a local argument; see Lemma III.6.5 of Kiehl R., Weissauer R.,  "Weil conjectures, perverse sheaves, and l'adic Fourier transform", Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete 42, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2001.

Answer (score 1):

Let z be a point of Z. Because f : Z --> X is finite, then O<sub>Z,z</sub> is an O<sub>X,f(z)</sub>-algebra of the same dimension. By assumption, O<sub>Y,z</sub> is an O<sub>X,f(z)</sub>-algebra of relative dimension d.

By the theory of regular sequences (see the refernce in the comments), the sequence f<sub>i,z</sub> in O<sub>Y,z</sub>, of stalks of the functions f<sub>i</sub>, is regular if the relative dimension of O<sub>Y,z</sub> over O<sub>Z,z</sub> = O<sub>Y,z</sub>/(f<sub>i,z</sub>) is equal to d. This is the case because of the assumptions. Therefor I conclude that the sequence is regular. This means that the embedding Z --> Y is a regular embedding. This implies that f : Z --> X is flat. Q.E.D.